# DOMPDF - Ordered Lists - Counters Issue

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation, dompdf, css-counter

I'm working with DOMPDF (version 0.8.0) And have a bunch of nested ordered lists to print. I have applied proper page breaks, but still the PDF bugs with the first line of all the pages (from 2nd page). 
This is my style:

```
ol { counter-reset: item; padding-left: 0; line-height: 1;}
ol > li{ counter-increment: item; list-style-type:none; padding-left:2.5em;position: relative; page-break-inside: avoid;}
ol li:before{ content:counters(item, ".") '. ' ; top: 0; left: 0; position:absolute; font-weight: bold;}
ol > li li{ padding-left:2.5em; page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

And this is the output section where I get issue:
**2nd page:**
[image]

**3rd page:**

[image]

Can anyone suggest a proper approach here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue. It seems a piece of code should be added to Frames file in DOMPDF. And the fix works like a charm.

[Reference link to the fix is here!](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/710)

Hope this helps someone. Thanks!